# Multiple inserts into a single table 

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Here I am facing one more challenging issue and as usual turning on this site to get help.

I have one web service which performs some business logic and finally insert the result in a table. This works fine if my application is in minimal load.

Now when the load is heavy, my `INSERT` SQL statement got timed out. I have increased my Connection Timeout and Command Timeout. But the problem is that there are too many threads calling the same web method. Just to give some hint, my number of OPEN sql connection in heavy load is goes to 500+. FYI, I did close my connection after every command.

Now what should I do here to optimize this thing here?

I am planning to store the `INSERT` data in data table and store this data table in APPLICATION variable. And after every two minutes, insert the data from this datatable to database.

Do you guys have any other idea here which can smoothen my life here?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Here are more details ,when i run insert query in management studio

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 11 ms.

Table 'IndexTable1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'IndexTable2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'fulltext_index_docidstatus_171147655'. Scan count 0, logical reads 11, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table '**MAINTABLE**'. Scan count 0, logical reads 28, physical reads 4, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 69 ms.

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Comment: How big is your connection pool?

Comment: You totally, absolutely need to benchmark your application to determine potential bottlenecks.  For starters, familiarize yourself with SQL Server "explain plan", check your indexes, and look at Windows performance monitor under load to check CPU, RAM and Disk I/O utilization. Look, too, at these links:  1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647768.aspx   2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx

Comment: Have you looked at the Producer/Consumer pattern to handle the inserts from a shared context, this way you could control the number of connections and use SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: Increasing timeouts is a very bad way of dealing with these situations. I agree with paulsm4; check your indexes, optimize your queries, use caching when necessary, but do not increase timeouts. Even only that itself may be the cause of your 500+ connections.

Comment: @paulsm4Its a simple INSERT statement in the SP but there are 4 indexes in the table i will check the EXECUTE PLAN option here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dedicated thread for inserting data into the DB. There's no point in opening a new connection for every insert statement, when instead you can insert data in big chunks once every few seconds. This thread can run on a dedicated dispatcher or even a timer, and you can use a thread-safe queue for inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 1):

Have ou thought about getting an appropriate server? Sorry to say, but the way you totally ignore anything hardware realted makes me think your database server is a - hm - "typical low end hosting machine" which is intrinsically unsuitable to run heavy SQL loads which are mostly IO bound and thus require high end IO subsystems.

Comment: I have  dedicated server with 4GM RAM with high CPU (dont remember its details) and only this application is running on the server

Comment: so, a toy (4gb RAM is a low end machine - average desktop memory) and likely one little desktop level disc? And you wonder IO overloads? An intro gbook into building database servers may be appropriate. CPU is mostly irrelevant for databases if your disc overloads, and normal discs are SLOW - 150 to 200 io operations per second.

Answer (score 0):

I know no easy answers to this question. First, your plan would go into concurrency problems, you will possibly try to lock your datatable, etc. and that may cause trouble.

As a rule of thumb, I would advise against a persistent connection between application and database servers. But on the other hand, your number of open connections being 500+ is something that shouldn't occur. I think that is the thing that you should focus on. I guess that your transaction is a big one, and it runs for more than a couple of seconds. Try to reduce it. I can offer writing your data to a very simple, unprocessed database table, like writing a log. And in an SQL job that runs periodically, read from that table and process them in parallel. You can even administer a system, in which when it detects a load it delays processing.

If you have several similar insert queries at one given point, you must consider the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy class, regardless of my statements above.

Wish you luck.

Comment: I have only one Insert statement in the SQL SP. I will give it a shot on SqlBulkCopy command. looks good alternative

Answer (score 0):

The answer to such a question may be overcomplicated

Try to figure out WHERE is the bottleneck - is it @ client or @ server side.

What amount of indexes involved to INSERT and if there is any *hotspot* on the top of your table - which is very usual for single-partition autoincrementing primary keyed table

Is there any simultaneous SELECTs performed over table when inserting into it

You should review all these and many other reasons to find out where is the problem.

Try to provide more valuable information in your question

Comment: There are SELECT statement performed over table concurrenly in the front end side, but all my SELECT are with NOLOCK option. So i think it should not create any problem

Answer (score 0):

Ilya Kogan's answer seems reasonable and it is on the same vein as yours. Basically doing bulk inserts on a scheduled basis. Just have in mind that this would only work if the info that you are inserting is not itself used in the business logic to respond to new requests. 
When you issue a response the client will assume that whatever change in state in the server has already happened whenever it decides to make a second request, here 2 problems arise: 1) what would happen if after responding to the client for whatever reason you could not insert the result of that request later on? 2) what would happen if upon receiving the response the client would issue a new request in such a fashion that the results of the first request were still not persisted? what would the application use as data to process this second request.
As you can see this apparently simple solution can lead to other problems but it all depends on how your web service is designed, specifically if any of the persisted data for each request is needed to process further requests.